# GHUnitIOS Build error

Tags: objective-c, ios, pch, gh-unit

I have been trying to get gh-unit working in an iOS project and I am getting a weird build error. I am using the 4.2 iOS SDK and XCode 3.2.5.

I followed this tutorial:

http://4arrowsmedia.com/2010/09/ghunit-setup/

And I am getting the same build error as the guy in the first comment.

```
expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '*' token
```

Interestingly I only get this error when using a .pch file. If I don't use one then everything runs fine. I would like to use a .pch file as I have lots of header files I use throughout the project and I don't want to include them in every file.

Comment: +1 I recently came across this same issue and am interested in a solution. I've posted to the GHUnit google group, but not reply yet. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ghunit/upQl4BYy3QU

Answer (score 0):

I just had this same problem and found that it was caused by having overlapping directories listed in my Header search paths.  When I removed the duplicate directory, the build succeeded.

In my case I had:

```
Libraries
|---RestKit
|---GHUnit.framework
```

I had included both Libraries/ (recursive) and Libraries/RestKit/ in my Header Search Path.  I removed Libraries/ and the build succeeded.